# JavaScript Get nested array (1 level) with quotes preserving numbers with console.log

Tags: javascript, arrays, client-side-scripting

How can I take something in the form of

`[["[]",2,"c"],["d","e","f"]]`

and log

`[["[]","2","c"],["d","e","f"]]`

to the console?
I have tried console.log(array.toString()) but that just logs

`[[[],2,c],[d,e,f]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify` and log that

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify([["[]",2,"c"],["d","e","f"]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to preserve double quotes `"` then you can use

console.log(`${'[["[]",2,"c"],["d","e","f"]]'}`)

else u can use

console.log(JSON.stringify([["[]",2,"c"],["d","e","f"]]))

Answer (score 0):

This will preserve the arrays and only turn the the inner array items into strings.

```js
var data = [["[]",2,"c"],["d","e","f"]];
var stringed = data.map((d)=>{
  return (d.toString().split(","))
});
console.log(stringed);
```